# How to make the ball widget gets deflected by rectangle widget in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Actually I am working on one gaming application in which I want the ball to get deflected by rectangle in the 90-degree direction of the movement of the ball. In the below code I am achieving the task but it is not as desired as it should be. The ball widget when button below is clicked collides with the rectangle widget and it first slides a little bit with it and then it gets deflected in the desired direction. I just want to make it realistic as the ball should deflect by rectangle widget just by colliding by it at one point. Try to execute the code below to understand more what I want to achieve and what problem I am having as it is a little bit difficult to explain it. Please help!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Rotate, Rectangle, Ellipse, Color
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, CardTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, 
NumericProperty,ReferenceListProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PopMatrix, PushMatrix

Builder.load_string('''

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<Game>:
    ball: pong_ball
    object: Object
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":2.6,"y":0}
            size_hint: 3, 1
            text:"Throw"
            background_color: 2,1,190,1
            border: 30,30,30,30
            on_release:
                root.start()

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'x':7.3, 'y':5.3}
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            text:'restart'
            on_release:
                root.serve_ball()

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.center

    Object:    
        id: Object
        center: self.rotate_origin

<Game1>:
    ball: pong_ball
    object1: Object1
    object2: Object2
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":2.6,"y":0}
            size_hint: 3, 1
            text:"Throw"
            background_color: 2,1,190,1
            border: 30,30,30,30
            on_release:
                root.start()

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'x':7.3, 'y':5.3}
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            text:'restart'
            on_release:
                root.serve_ball()

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.center

    Object1:
        id: Object1
        center: self.rotate_origin
    Object2:
        id: Object2
        center: self.rotate_origin

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    Screen:
        name:"P"
        FloatLayout:

            Button:
                pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
                text: "Play"
                background_color: 255,0,1,1
                on_release:
                    root.transition.direction = "up";s3.serve_ball()        
                    root.current = "again"

    Screen:
        name: 'again'
        Game1:
            id:s3
''')
class Object1(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 370
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 200
        self.rect_height = 30
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        print('rect 1')
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0,197,68))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
            PopMatrix()

    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.angle += 90
        if (self.angle > 315):
            self.angle = 225
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)

    def deflect_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            if not ball.collided:
                vx, vy = ball.velocity
                if self.angle == 135:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                if self.angle == 225:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(270)
                if self.angle == 315:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                ball.collided = True
        else:
            ball.collided = False


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.rotate()
            print(self.angle)

class Object2(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 170
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 200
        self.rect_height = 30
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        print('rect 1')
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0,197,68))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
            PopMatrix()

    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.angle += 90 
        if (self.angle > 315):
            self.angle = 225
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
            PopMatrix()
    def deflect_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            if not ball.collided:
                vx, vy = ball.velocity
                if self.angle == 135:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                if self.angle == 225:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(270)
                if self.angle == 315:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                ball.collided = True
        else:    
            ball.collided = False


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.rotate()
            print(self.angle)

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
    collided = BooleanProperty(None)


    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

class Game1(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    object1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    object2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    def start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(5, 0)):
        Clock.unschedule(self.update)
        self.ball.center = 40, 380
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.object1.deflect_ball(self.ball)
        self.object2.deflect_ball(self.ball)

        if (self.ball.y < self.y+50) or self.ball.x <0:
            self.ball.velocity_y = 0
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            print('tested')
            self.serve_ball()

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = Manager()

class ScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.   
Remove all of the display overhead.  Track the position of the ball, and point out where it differs from what you want.

Comment: Note the the `pos` attribute of the `Ellipse` is its lower left corner (not the center). Perhaps not what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after a collision is detected and the ball velocity is changed, the next `update` does not move the ball far enough for the `collide_widget()` method to return `False` instead of `True`. One way to fix that is to keep a `collided` property for the `PongBall` that can be used to avoid multiple collides.
So you can add a `DictProperty` to `PongBall` as:

```
collided = DictProperty()
```

where each key in the `DictProperty` is an `Object`, and the value is `True` or `False`.

and modify `deflect_ball` to:

```
def deflect_ball(self, ball):
    if self.collide_widget(ball):
        if not ball.collided[self]:
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            if self.angle == 135:
                ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
            if self.angle == 225:
                ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(270)
            if self.angle == 315:
                ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
            ball.collided[self] = True
    else:
        ball.collided[self] = False
```

And the property needs to be initialized in the `Game1` as:

```
def start(self):
    self.ball.collided[self.object1] = False
    self.ball.collided[self.object2] = False
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
```

Comment: Amazing @JohnAnderson, you solved my problem again...Thank you so much!... Just one help more, When I am implementing the above code to my code it is solving the problem in only one screen and the multiple rectangles present on other screens are having the same problem that was there before...Please help!

Comment: I have also edited the code above so that you could help me by efforting less...Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Modified my answer to handle multiple Objects.

Comment: Brilliant @JohnAnderson! Thank you very much again...you solved it again :) Just one thing more, the ball in the above code(including your correction) gets deflected some distance before colliding with the rectangles...Is there any way to solve this problem? just try to run the code to check what's happening here!

Comment: The problem is the `collide_widget()` uses `Widget` `pos` and `size` to determine collisions. It is not looking at your `canvas` instructions. You can see this clearly by adding a `canvas.before:` block (for each object and the ball) that draws a `Rectangle` with the `pos` and `size` of the object/ball. A solution is to write your own `collide()` method that does a better calculation. I think that would be a candidate for a separate posting after you give it a try yourself.

Comment: Thank you @JohnAnderson, I am getting what you are explaining...I have posted a separate question on the same problem after trying myself...actually I am on the learning phase so it is little bit difficult for me to solve the problems like this...so please help me by answering on that post...Thanks in advance :)